# Automatic Lyx newcommands

Tags: lyx

I am starting to gather a list of LyX macroes that I use frequently - \del to \nabla, for example. I'd like a way to automate this. Making *.sty files and putting it in the default preamble seems to make the pdf do what I want, but part of the reason I use LyX is that I can work entirely within LyX, much like I would solve equations with pen and paper, and having a symbol not show up properly until I export it is annoying.

Is there a way to automate \newcommands, so that both the LaTeX compiler and LyX's reader recognize them?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "automatic"? Can you give a step-by-step of what you would like to do, e.g. how you would like to create an "automatic \newcommand" and how you would like to use it (e.g. menu/shortcut/etc.). Please take a look at "Flex insets" in Help > Customization. Is that what you want?

Comment: I'd like to open up a new document and have it already ready to go, in the same way as I could throw a newcommand into the preamble and set it as "Document Default."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it (probably the only way) is to put the commands in to their own LyX file. You can then include it in other LyX documents as a child document (insert->file->child document). Make sure you include the .lyx extension in the file name box.

When you do this, change the "include type" in that dialogue box from "include" to "input", because otherwise you'll never be able to use the outer document as a child document itself e.g. as a chapter in a book. If you do ever end up in that situation, it's fine that each of your chapters has the macro file inputted, even though it's obviously redundant, so long as the macro file contains nothing except for the macros. You'll be able to typeset each of your chapters individually as well as the whole document.